# How to call a different drawable animation for each click in one imageview?

Tags: android, animation, imageview, animationdrawable

i have 10 image files.
I want to play my pictures in sequential order every time I click imageview like 1-2,2-3,3-4....1-2,2-3...but when I click on imageview, only the first xml file is working.Please help me

```
    imageView=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.animationtesbih);
    imageView.setClickable(true);

    animation=(AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();

    imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

             animation=(AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();
             animation.start();

             imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a1);
             imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a2);

        }
    });
```

here my xml name a1

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <animation-list 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
     android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/t2" android:duration="70"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/t3" android:duration="70"/>

   </animation-list>
```

here other xml file name animationtesbih

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <animation-list 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:oneshot="true">
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/t1" android:duration="70"/>
   <item android:drawable="@drawable/t2" android:duration="70"/>
</animation-list>
```

other xml name a2

```
    <animation-list 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/t3" android:duration="70"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/t4" android:duration="70"/>

   </animation-list>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
animation=(AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();

imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

         animation=(AnimationDrawable) imageView.getBackground();

         animation.start();

         imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.a1);

    }
});
```

Comment: worked but  I cant switch to the other xml file (a2 for 3-4)